# Extracting text from 'value' attribute using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributes

HTML Code:

```
<td id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Product_eBay1_tdBINPrice">
    <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Product_eBay1_txtBuyItNowPrice" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$Product_eBay1$txtBuyItNowPrice" 
    style="width:50px;" type="text" value="1435.97"/>                           
    <img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Product_eBay1_imgCustomPriceCalculator" src="/images/ChannelPriceCustom.png" style="width:16px;"/>
</td>
```

i would like to extra the text in 'Value' attribute ('1435.95')

i tried doing it by executing the following code, but no luck.

```
driver.get(someURL)
       page = driver.page_source
       soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
       price = soup.find('td', {'id' : re.compile('ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Product_eBay1_tdBINPrice')})

       print(price)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<td id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Product_eBay1_tdBINPrice">
    <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Product_eBay1_txtBuyItNowPrice" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$Product_eBay1$txtBuyItNowPrice" 
    style="width:50px;" type="text" value="1435.97"/>                           
    <img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Product_eBay1_imgCustomPriceCalculator" src="/images/ChannelPriceCustom.png" style="width:16px;"/>
</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

textval=soup.select_one("input[name='ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$Product_eBay1$txtBuyItNowPrice']")
print(textval['value'])
```

OR

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<td id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Product_eBay1_tdBINPrice">
    <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Product_eBay1_txtBuyItNowPrice" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$Product_eBay1$txtBuyItNowPrice" 
    style="width:50px;" type="text" value="1435.97"/>                           
    <img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Product_eBay1_imgCustomPriceCalculator" src="/images/ChannelPriceCustom.png" style="width:16px;"/>
</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

textval=soup.find("input" ,attrs={"name" : "ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$Product_eBay1$txtBuyItNowPrice"})
print(textval['value'])
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an id which is the fastest selector. Use that to get the element then take the value attribute. Yours in part is failing as you are looking at td not input tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html = '''
<td id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Product_eBay1_tdBINPrice">
    <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Product_eBay1_txtBuyItNowPrice" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$Product_eBay1$txtBuyItNowPrice" 
    style="width:50px;" type="text" value="1435.97"/>                           
    <img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Product_eBay1_imgCustomPriceCalculator" src="/images/ChannelPriceCustom.png" style="width:16px;"/>
</td>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
soup.select_one('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Product_eBay1_txtBuyItNowPrice')['value']
```

---

Yours (with input):

```
print(soup.find("input", {"id": "ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_Product_eBay1_txtBuyItNowPrice"})['value'])
```